# Laravel 5.7 Undefined Variable

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm working to show products in a separate index.blade.php page but the page is not opening and it gives the error:

> Undefined variable: productsALL

```
@foreach($productsALL as $product)
    <img src="{{ asset('images/backend_images/products/small/'.$product->image) }}" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
    {{ $product->product_name }}
@endforeach
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/','IndexController@index');
```

**IndexController**

```
public function index()
{
    // Get all Products
    $productsAll = Product::inRandomOrder()->where('status', 1)->get();
    $productsAll = json_decode(json_encode($productsAll));

    // Get All Categories and Sub Categories
    $categories_menu = '';
    $categories = Category::with('categories')->where(['parent_id' => 0])->get();
    $categories = json_decode(json_encode($categories));
    /*echo "<pre>"; print_r($categories); die;*/
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        $categories_menu .= "
        <div class='panel-heading'>
            <h4 class='panel-title'>
                <a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordian' href='#" . $cat->id . "'>
                    <span class='badge pull-right'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></span>
                    " . $cat->name . "
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id='" . $cat->id . "' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
            <div class='panel-body'>
                <ul>";
        $sub_categories = Category::where(['parent_id' => $cat->id])->get();
        foreach ($sub_categories as $sub_cat) {
            $categories_menu .= "<li><a href='#'>" . $sub_cat->name . " </a></li>";
        }
        $categories_menu .= '</ul>
            </div>
        </div>';
    }

    $banners = Banner::where('status', '1')->get();

    return view('index')->with(compact('productsAll', 'categories_menu', 'categories', 'banners'));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

the wrong part is here

```
return view('index')->with(compact('productsAll','categories_menu','categories','banners'));
```

change it to this

```
return view('index',compact('productsAll','categories_menu','categories','banners'));
```

hope it works

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable from controller to view by using both the with and compact method.

1)First method,
`$data=array('productsAll'=>$productsAll, 'categories_menu'=>$categories_menu, 'categories'=>$categories);
return view('view')->with($data);`

2) Second method,
 `//Mostly i used this method for passing data in view`
`return view('index',compact('productsAll','categories_menu','categories','banners'));`

**OR,**

`$data=array('productsAll','categories_menu','categories','banners');
return view('view')->compact($data);`